# Data from database updating live

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice 5.1 and PostgreSQL 9.5. I need to have data from a database table available in Calc and those data in Calc should update when underlying database data change.

I've registered the database using LibreOffice Base. I don't know what to do next. I've seen [this tutorial](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=18511) but pressing F4 does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Does *nothing* happen, or does something happen, but it is different from what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu command is `View -> Data Sources`.  On my system, the key combination in LibreOffice is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, and in Apache OpenOffice it is <kbd>F4</kbd>.

**EDIT**: (in response to your comment)

The Refresh toolbar button is just for the Data Sources window.  From Villeroy's instructions that you linked:

> Refresh the imported range: Click a single cell in the imported range, call menu:Data>Refresh...

In LibreOffice the menu command is `Data -> Refresh Range`.

Comment: Now I can see databases. I can drag&drop table or query into sheet. But then values are copied, no link created. When I change data outside LibreOffice and press `refresh` button on Calc toolbar the data in preview is updated and data in sheet is not.